# Cannot reference subquery column by outer order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, subquery

The `ORDER BY` clause below is causing an error. How can I reference the TotalPrice column in `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM
(

SELECT O.OrderID,
       (SELECT SUM(SubTotal) FROM DB_OrderDetails OD WHERE OD.OrderID = O.OrderID) AS TotalPrice,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalPrice) AS RowNum

    FROM DB_Orders O

) Orders
```

Comment: Can you also explain in English what you are trying to do? It appears that a simple thing got complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
select 
    o.orderID,
    sum(od.SubTotal) as TotalPrice,
    row_number() over (order by sum(od.SubTotal)) as RowNum
from DB_Orders o
join DB_OrderDetails od
    on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
group by o.OrderID
```

Here is the example: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/945a9/2)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot reference it by its name in the same sub-query, you nave to do it in the outer query:

```
SELECT orders.*, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalPrice) AS RowNum FROM
(
    SELECT O.OrderID,
       (SELECT SUM(SubTotal) FROM DB_OrderDetails OD 
        WHERE OD.OrderID = O.OrderID) AS TotalPrice
    FROM DB_Orders O
) Orders
```